# Magento empty cart event

Tags: events, magento, shopping-cart

I'm a real newb in Magento, there's a button in the cart page that empty the cart's content. I'm trying to find the event triggered by this action, I tried checkout_quote_destroy but is not that one, neither sales_quote_remove_item.

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is log all events, and search through them for the proper event:

1. Open: `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php`
2. Search for: `public function dispatchEvent($eventName, $args) {`
3. Add this line below: `Mage::log("Event name: $eventName");`
4. Look in `var\log\system.log` you will see a long list of events.

Comment: From the long list what I was able to filter was the custom_quote_process event; however this event is being dispatched inside the getQuote function of Mage/Checkout/Model/Session.php. This makes me doubt a little and makes me think that maybe this event could be triggered in other situations. Any advice?

Comment: Also the event is triggered multiple times so I don't think is that one

Comment: I noticed that none of the events were particular to the empty cart functionality; I manually fired the event in the removeAllItems function in Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php